# How to completely destroy session variables on logout

Tags: php, session-variables

When I log a user out of an app I am building I use `session_destroy();`

But when I go back to the page, all session variables are still set.

How can I completely destroy all session variables and ultimately require a user to log back in again?

Here is my code:

```
session_unset(); // clears all session variables
$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy(); // deletes session id
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

After using session_destroy(), the session cookie is removed and the session is no longer stored on the server. The values in $_SESSION may still be available, but they will not be on the next page load.

If you need to clear the values of $_SESSION, set the array equal to an empty array:

Of course, you can't access the values of $_SESSION on another page once you call session_destroy, so it doesn't matter that much.Still if you are concerned .

Try the following:

```
session_destroy();
$_SESSION = array(); // Clears the $_SESSION variable
```

Comment: That worked -- thanks @SoneshDadhi. I don't have a good enough reputation to up vote your answer and I need to wait 10 minutes to accept this as the answer. I am moving on so if anyone else want s to accept this as the answer please do so. Thanks.

Comment: @frank13: You, not anyone else, should mark this answer as accepted, disregarding you have enough reputation or not. Those 10 minutes have long passed.

Answer (score 0):

you are not calling session_destroy() for sure, your code may be unable to access it.

Post more code so we could help you